# SessionID Shifts in IE8 Forms Authentication issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, forms-authentication

Recently I noticed issues with the login process of a website I maintain.

When logging into the site with IE8 the .authuser cookie set by forms authentication shifts UIDs. This does not happen in any other browser I have tested. [ie6, ie7, ie9, FF6, FF7, FF8, Chrome, Safari]

1. User visits site. Clean browser session.
2. User is given a .authuser cookie with a UID
3. User goes to login page and logs in
4. User succeeds at login and is redirected
5. User is given a new .authuser cookie UID value

The biggest issue that comes from this is the fact that the login cookies set actually allow the user to return as 'partially authenticated' like on amazon. This means that the user can do all sorts of things on the site related to session, and when they log in using IE8, all that data is lost and corrupts certain processes in the site.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you duplicated this behavior on a another machine running IE8?

Comment: Yes I have experienced this issue on multiple machines running IE8

Comment: Solved this issue. Turns out there was a major bug in the way that the legacy session "enhancements" that are part of the software when storing the sessionid. Turns out this was all in-house and we are going to address this under lying issue. Thanks for the input +jesse

Comment: Sorry, for not being able to provide any further input. Never heard of an issue quite like what you described.